# Retrieve row from a table column with a value other than empty string in sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I wanna retrieve rows of a table where the column(in my case its called 'notes') contain any value other than empty string.

I already tried the below code but no luck.

```
    final res = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE notes=?", [!null]);
```

> Is there any way i can retrieve rows? Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE notes!=?", [""])`?

Comment: I tried now but says, error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot the braces. Try now

Comment: So this fetches all the list that has empty string. i want the opposite of that. I wanna fetch a row that contains string of data.